# Require a new page in a wiki to use a template

Tags: templates, mediawiki, preload

Let's say I want to make a wiki of addresses, using a `Template:Address`. How do I make it so that, if someone goes to a new page — e.g. `myaddresswiki.com/John_Smith` — to add their address, it automatically includes my `Template:Address` in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Manual:Creating pages with preloaded text](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCreating_pages_with_preloaded_text) at mediawiki.org.

If you're manually creating edit links for your users to add the new pages, you can just [include a `preload=SomePageName` parameter in the URL](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Options_affecting_the_edit_form).

Alternatively, you can use one of the [extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCreating_pages_with_preloaded_text#Extensions) that automate parts of the process for you (typically either by generating the appropriate links and/or automatically selecting a preload template based on the page title), or even write your own using the [EditFormPreloadText hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/EditFormPreloadText).

Answer (score 1):

I just did it this way:

```
if( $("#wpTextbox1").val() == ""){
     $("#wpTextbox1").val("This content is generated from 'MediaWiki:Common.js'\rPlease use a template by typing into the Search field 'Template:'.  From there, your available templates will be visible from the auto-complete options.");
}
```

Of course, you could hard-code a template (or anything) into the val argument.